# SQL Oracle UNION with only a parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have this query in ORACLE SQL:

```
select W.x, 'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=?
   union select to_number(W.x || '0000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=?
   union select to_number(W.x || '1000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=?
   union select to_number(W.x || '2000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=?
   union select to_number(W.x || '3000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=?
   union select to_number(W.x || '4000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=?
order by 1
```

I would like to pass only a same parameter, because it will be used in a special solution that only have a parameter.

I mean, an only **?** with the same value but the UNION must be exists.

All the values are numerics.

Comment: OK, so pass the same parameter to all those SELECTs. I don't understand what prevents you from doing that.

Comment: @Littlefoot for example if I use Intellij DataGrid with this query, it asks for six parameters. But I need to asks only for one same parameter to use in all UNIONs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented that you might be using a tool (Intellij DataGrid) I don't know.

However, if you modify the query a little bit so that

- your current query is used as an inline view
- add a new - `z` - column to it
- apply alias to the 2nd column to be returned (`result`)
- move `where` clause out of the subquery

then this *might* work:

```
select x, result
from 
(
select           W.x,           'RESULT ' || W.x result, W.z from W union all
select to_number(W.x || '0000'),'RESULT ' || W.x       , W.z from W union all
select to_number(W.x || '1000'),'RESULT ' || W.x       , W.z from W union all
select to_number(W.x || '2000'),'RESULT ' || W.x       , W.z from W union all
select to_number(W.x || '3000'),'RESULT ' || W.x       , W.z from W union all
select to_number(W.x || '4000'),'RESULT ' || W.x       , W.z from W  
)
where z = ?
order by 1;
```

---

Other than that, if you used SQL*Plus, you'd

```
select           W.x,           'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=&&par_z union all
select to_number(W.x || '0000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=&&par_z union all
select to_number(W.x || '1000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=&&par_z union all
select to_number(W.x || '2000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=&&par_z union all
select to_number(W.x || '3000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=&&par_z union all
select to_number(W.x || '4000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=&&par_z 
order by 1;
```

Running it, you'd be prompted for `par_z` value and get the result. Between two subsequent query calls, you'd have to `undefine par_z` so that it asks for a new value.

---

Or, it could be a function that returns e.g. refcursor:

```
create or replace function f_test (par_z in number) 
  return sys_refcursor
is
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_rc for
    select           W.x,           'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=par_z union all
    select to_number(W.x || '0000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=par_z union all
    select to_number(W.x || '1000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=par_z union all
    select to_number(W.x || '2000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=par_z union all
    select to_number(W.x || '3000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=par_z union all
    select to_number(W.x || '4000'),'RESULT ' || W.x from W where W.z=par_z 
    order by 1;
end;
```

You'd call it as e.g.

```
select f_test(10) from dual;
```

Comment: HI Littlefoot. It is normal practice for editors to remove "hope that helps" and other phrases that are chatty or invite discussion. Readers know to ask for elucidation in the comments. I make these edits to low-rep users as a matter of course, and in order to be as even-handed as possible, I thus make them to high-rep users too.

Comment: If it makes you happy, @halfer, no problem.

Comment: Dunno about "happy" - it's probably some undiagnosed OCD that got out of control 

Answer (score 0):

Another somewhat more efficient solution would be like this.

I assume W.x is a number, but that is not clear from your original query.
If it is not then add a to_number(W.x) in the with clause.

```
with src as
  ( select W.x as x from W where W.z = ?
  )
select src.x               , 'RESULT ' || to_char(src.x) from src union all
select src.x * 10000       , 'RESULT ' || to_char(src.x) from src union all
select src.x * 10000 + 1000, 'RESULT ' || to_char(src.x) from src union all
select src.x * 10000 + 2000, 'RESULT ' || to_char(src.x) from src union all
select src.x * 10000 + 3000, 'RESULT ' || to_char(src.x) from src union all
select src.x * 10000 + 4000, 'RESULT ' || to_char(src.x) from src
order by 1
;
```